# Emacs for MS Windows 10 Anniversary edition cannot find WSL bash

Tags: windows, bash, shell, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Emacs uses shells to execute many commands - a handy feature. Most emacs Windows users install Cygwin32 to access common bash commands.  But with Windows 10 Anniversary edition bash is provided "natively" by Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).  There should be no reason any more for Cygwin32.  Unhappily, Emacs for MS Windows cannot seem to find WSL's bash.  I get the following message when typing M-x shell:   Searching for program: no such file or directory, bash.  Is there some reason why this will not work?

Comment: Is it in your PATH?

Comment: 1. Make sure you have WSL active. 2. Make sure you have `c:\windows\system32` in your path (hardly believe you don't). 3. To check, do `Win-R bash` (or `bash` in a command prompt) and confirm you run bash indeed, 4. Check what you have in `shell` customization group in `explicit-shell-file-name`, maybe it shows a different directory. 5. Try to set that variable to `bash`. If after all this you get a running Windows bash under emacs, please report back here, because bash crashes on me when I try to run it under emacs (runs perfectly well otherwise.)